# How to set the size of dynamically created bootstrap Carousel images to desktop size regardless of uploaded image size

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried something like this but it is not properly fitting to the screen of the window.
There is a space to scroll up and down but it should not be there if it properly fit to the screen.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var $item = $('.carousel .item');
        var $Wwidth = $(window).width();
        $item.eq(0).addClass('active');
        $item.width($Wwidth);
        $item.addClass('full-screen');

        $(window).on('resize', function () {
            $item.width($Wwidth);
        });                    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed this issue by declaring a height variable as shown below. If any one faces the same problem this would help them.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var $item = $('.carousel .item');
        var $Wwidth = $(window).width();
        var $wHeight = $(window).height();
        $item.eq(0).addClass('active');
        $item.height($wHeight);
        $item.width($Wwidth);
        $item.addClass('full-screen');

        $(window).on('resize', function () {
            $item.height($wHeight);
            $item.width($Wwidth);
        });

    });
```